FormBuilder: hidden date with default "Today" is not correct when saved
Dates in FormBuilder that were hidden and had default value from Relative Date Filters, e.g. Today, is using fallback or default date of 1970-01-0 when saved (probably default from database). It seems that "this.day" was not converted as I check the value in affor_submissions table it was still "this.day", but not really sure.
